# Almond essence substitute

Tags: baking

Can you substitute Almond liqueur or use ground almonds, instead of  using Almond essence in a Christmas Cake recipe? I can't find Almond Essence in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find almond extract, that would probably be the best substitute. It is generally stronger than almond essence, so you may want to decrease the amount you use. You could use almond liqueur, but it will likely be less strong, so you may want to use a bit more. Ground almonds will change the characteristics of your batter and final cake, so you would need to adapt the recipe to compensate.

Comment: If you give enough almond liqueur to your guests, they won't notice what the cake tastes like.